How to show snackbar when call api success riverpod flutter using AsyncNotifier
since it update AsyncNotifier, I still don't know how to do it like:
final tableServices = Provider<TableServices>((ref) => TableServices());

class TableServices {
  Future<void> themMon(AddMealToTableRequest item) async {

final response = await addMealToTable(item);

if (response.ErrorMsg != '') {
  throw Exception(response.ErrorMsg);
  // then show alert dialog ..
} else {
  return  //state true or sthing to show snackbar
}
 }
}

I want to add a meal to the table, it make api call then if it work, the response.data and response.error message would be '', or return some error if it not working.
So I want to show snackbar listen to it but don't know how to, I try the old one StateNotifier but went wrong, I used to use Provider before. Read and watch a lot of tutorial but don't find out.
So what to do next to declare the listener

If you call themMon from a ConsumerWidget/ConsumerState, you can have this method :
void showSnackBar(BuildContext context, String message) {
  const snackBar = SnackBar(
    content: Text(message),
  );
  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
}

Then modify your function like this :
Future<void> themMon(BuildContext context, AddMealToTableRequest item) async {
  final response = await addMealToTable(item);

  if (response.ErrorMsg != '') {
    // Show the error snackbar
    if(context.mounted) showSnackBar(context, 'Error');
    throw Exception(response.ErrorMsg);
  } else { 
    // Show the success snackbar
    if(context.mounted) showSnackBar(context, 'Success');
  }
}

Finally you can call the method from your widget like this :
await ref.read(tableServices).themMon(context, item);

